# C++ Making Pointer of Class type

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm new to C++ and can't figure out this error.

I'm trying to make a pointer type for the class `Player`. From all of the tutorials I've seen, this should be the proper syntax for declaring a pointer of type `Player` in a header file.

```
Player* player = new Player;
```

[EDIT, accidentally posted before finished]

But I get the error " must use 'class' tag to refer to type 'Player' in this scope". I've used `#include "Player.h"`.

What's going on here?

EDIT
All of these give the same error

```
    Player* player;
    Player* player = new Player;
    Player* player = new Player();
```

This header file for `Player`

```
#ifndef PLAYER_H
#define PLAYER_H

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

#include "Item.h"
#include "GlobalDefs.h"

class Player
{ 

public:

    // constructor
    Player( void );

    // destructor
    virtual ~Player( void );


    inline gold_t GetGold( void ) 
    {
        return gold;
    }

    void AddGold(gold_t amount);
    void RemoveGold(gold_t amount);
    std::string GetInventoryString(void);
    void AddItem(Item);

private:
    gold_t gold;
    Item item;
    std::vector <Item> inventory;

};

#endif  /* PLAYER_H */
```

This is the header file where the pointer (`Player* player = new Player;`) is being defined.

```
#ifndef STOREAREA_H
#define STOREAREA_H

#include "AreaAbstract.h"
#include "Player.h"
#include <iostream>

class StoreArea : public AreaAbstract{
     typedef void (StoreArea::*AreaInput)( void );

public:
    StoreArea(*Player);
    StoreArea();

    ~StoreArea();

    void PrintAreaText();
    bool RecieveInput(std::string);


protected:
    void PurchaseHelm();
    std::map <std::string, AreaInput> areaInputMap;

    Player* player;


};

#endif  /* STOREAREA_H */
```

Comment: C++ has no `class tag(s)`

Comment: To "make a pointer" all you need is `Player* player;`.

Comment: Where is `Player` declared? Can you show us that code?

Comment: Where exactly are you making these declarations? Provide a [MCVE]

Comment: @DieterLücking The message refers to using `class Player` instead of just `Player`. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ced5356b9878f601).

Comment: @DieterLücking: Sure it does.

Comment: Your `PLAYER_H` comment at the bottom of that file is unclosed, and you have `StoreArea(*Player);` where I assume you mean `StoreArea(Player*);`. I'm assuming these are typos in copy-paste but make sure they are not in your actual code that way.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have a variable or other identifier (other than the class) named `Player` somewhere, and the error message is suggesting to use:

```
Player* player = new class Player;
```

to disambiguate between the two `Player`s.

The simplest solution would be the rename the non-class `Player` to something else, e.g. `player`.